# Lenguaje C | programa en c que captura, muestra y elimina elementos de un vector, tengo problema con la opcion de eliminar, me pueden orientar?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Estoy empezando a programar.
La acción de eliminar tiene que borrar el valor contenido dentro del vector, y si el valor se repite en otra posición, también borrarlo y recorrer las posiciones.

```
por ejemplo: V={ 1, 3, 8, 6, 1, 5, 1 },
```

Tengo que eliminar todos los 1.

este es mi codigo:

```
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    int x, v[7], op, posicion=-1, band=0,eli;
    do
    {
        printf("\nMENU:\n 1.CAPTURAR\n 2.MOSTRAR\n 3.ELIMINAR\n 4.SALIR\n OPCION: ");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:
            printf("\nCapturar un numero: ");
            if(posicion==6)
                printf("\nLLENO\n");
            else
            {
                posicion++;
                scanf("%d",&v[posicion]);
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            if(posicion==-1)
                printf("\nVACIO\n");
            else
                for(x=0;x<=posicion;x++)
                printf("\n%d",v[x]);
            break;
        default:
            printf("\nOPCION INVALIDA.\n");
        case 3:

            break;
        case 4:
            break;
        }

        }while(op!=4);
    printf("\nFIN DEL PROGRAMA.\n");
    printf("PROGRAMA REALIZADO POR ALEJANDRO.");
    getch();
    return 0;
    };
```

Comment: Y cuál es el problema con el código?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con eliminarlos? Esto puede ser reemplazarlos por un valor, por ejemplo 0, o desplazar los valores que le siguen, de forma que el nuevo array será más pequeño. En el primer caso faltaría decir cual es el valor por el que se reemplaza y en el segundo ... bueno, aquí habría que decidir si creas un array nuevo o qué mecanismo usarías para determinar que has llegado al final del array.

Comment: Por otro lado no estaría de más que editases la pregunta para indicar cómo has intentado eliminar tu esos elementos y así de paso aprovechas para incluir en el cuerpo de la misma que el problema lo tienes justamente en esa parte